# Send email to multiple recipients based on selected option in php?

Tags: php, html, email

Good evening everyone,

I've been currently trying to send an email to the according recipient based on the selected option they've chose on the email form before sending. For example, you open the form, type your name in and so on.. And you see the option "I'm a customer, I'm the press, etc" and I choose "I'm the press".. It should now send to press@domain.com and that's it based on their selection.

I'm not the best with PHP and been trying this for awhile and I feel like I'm pretty close but can close in the last very details. I've also looked at some previous answers and I'm trying to do as little reworking as possible since I know this isn't too tough. Would anyone mind, tell me what I'm doing wrong so that it's not sending? I've felt like I've defined the right things, but not sure what's happening.

Here's my PHP..

```
<?php

// We use the name2 field as bait for spambots.  It's display is off,
// so humans wouldn't know to enter anything into it.  Robots would, 
//  so we ignore submissions with info in name2.

$mail_sent = false;

if(sizeof($_POST) && $_POST["name2"] == "") // receiving a submission
{   
    define("SUBJECT",   "Visitor Message from Website");

    // production recipient:
    define("RECIPIENT", ".$department.");

    // prep our data from the form info
    $senderName     = $_POST['name'];
    $senderEmail    = $_POST['email'];
    $department     = $_POST['department'];
    $subject        = SUBJECT; 
    $messageBody    = $senderName . ' ('.$senderEmail.') wrote in '.$department.':

' . $_POST['message'];

    if($department == 'customer') { //if customer was selected
    $to = 'customer@gmail.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'distribution') { //if distribution was selected
    $to = 'distribution@email.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'press') { //if press was selected
    $to = 'press@email.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'career') { //if career was selected
    $to = 'career@email.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'other') { //if other was selected
    $to = 'other@email.com';
    }

    // From 
    $header         = "from: $senderName <$senderEmail>";

    // To
    $to = RECIPIENT;

    // Send it!
    $send_contact = mail($to, $subject, $messageBody, $header);

    // Check success of send attempt
    if($send_contact){
        // show thankyou screen
        $mail_sent = true;
    }
    else {
        // send failed.
        echo "ERROR";
    }
}

?>
```

And here is the form itself!

```
    <form action="contact-form.php" id="contactForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" minlength="2" placeholder="Your Name&hellip;" required>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email&hellip;" required>
        <input id="name2" type="text" name="name2" placeholder="Your Last Name&hellip;" required>
        <select id="department" type="text" name="department">
          <option value="customer" name="customer">I am a customer</option>
          <option value="distribution" name="distribution">department in distribution</option>
          <option value="press" name="press">I am with the press</option>
          <option value="career" name="career">department in a career position</option>
          <option value="other" name="other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message&hellip;" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send away!">
    </form>
```

Any help is kindly appreciated. Have a great week everyone!

Comment: what error are you getting? Is sizeof($_POST) valid, should it be $_POST['name2']

Comment: Sidenote: This `$subject = SUBJECT;` --- `SUBJECT` needs to be encapsulated with quotes. I'm questioning the dots in `define("RECIPIENT", ".$department.");`

Comment: Sidenote #2: To send to multiple recipients using `<select>` you need to use (Basic syntax)=> `<select multiple>`  then base yourself on the answer given below.

Comment: I'm technically getting no errors and it's "sending" fine and when I remove the periods from ".$department." it echos and error which I made it do, not sure to find out the exact error.

And shall I change my SUBJECT from..

`$subject = SUBJECT;` to `$subject = "SUBJECT";`?

Comment: Yes, change it to `$subject = "SUBJECT";` because you will get a parse error otherwise. @DoPeT

Comment: @Fred-ii- Technically not, it's worked before with that in there. But, I'm still trying to get it to send to the right email based on selection (or even get an email through at least). Thanks for the fast replies!

Comment: @Fred-ii-I've changed..

`define("RECIPIENT", ".$department.");`

to..

`define("RECIPIENT", "email@email.com");`

And it sends the email fine now, and my code..

`$messageBody    = $senderName . ' ('.$senderEmail.') wrote in '.$department.':`

Shows in my email that the right department is being read, but now the problem is how do I get the recipient define part to automatically send to email that they chose the selection?

Comment: You're welcome. I made a few tests and managed to echo the department emails, yet am unsure about `if(sizeof($_POST) && $_POST["name2"] == "")` when I took that out, it worked. I can post an answer which works, but will be different than what you have now; about 20% different.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49336/discussion-between-dopet-and-fred-ii)

Comment: You may have to reload my answer, I changed the brace `}` location for the `if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST["name2"] != "")` a minute ago. @DoPeT which is now located at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, however this line `if(sizeof($_POST) && $_POST["name2"] == "")` did not work in my tests.

I suggest you change it to `if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST["name2"] != "")` (which is in my answer).

What this essentially says is, *"if not empty AND name2 does not equal nothing, then proceed"*

```
<?php
// We use the name2 field as bait for spambots.  It's display is off,
// so humans wouldn't know to enter anything into it.  Robots would, 
//  so we ignore submissions with info in name2.

$mail_sent = false;

if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST["name2"] != ""){

 // receiving a submission
    $to = $_POST['department'];

    // prep our data from the form info
    $senderName     = $_POST['name'];
    $senderEmail    = $_POST['email'];
    $department     = $_POST['department'];
    $subject        = "Visitor Message from Website"; 
    $messageBody    = $senderName . ' ('.$senderEmail.') wrote in '.$department.': ' . $_POST['message'];

    if($department == 'customer') { //if customer was selected
    $to = 'customer@gmail.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'distribution') { //if distribution was selected
    $to = 'distribution@email.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'press') { //if press was selected
    $to = 'press@email.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'career') { //if career was selected
    $to = 'career@email.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'other') { //if other was selected
    $to = 'other@email.com';
    }

    // From 
    $header = "From: $senderName <$senderEmail>";

    // echo $to; // my testing purpose


    // Send it!

    $send_contact = mail($to, $subject, $messageBody, $header);

    if($send_contact){
        $mail_sent = true;
    }
    else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }


// end brace for if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST["name2"] != "")
 }

?>
```

Comment: You're probably the most awesome person for taking your time AND also helping me in the chatroom on your weekend. Kudos buddy.

Comment: You're very much welcome @DoPeT I was happy to help and find a solution. All the best