# Send email based on selection (with file upload)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create a page for my website, where students have to select 3 or less out of about 10 choices(multiple selection). They also need to upload a file below this. When they click submit finally, it would send the file they uploaded to multiple email addresses (or even a specific single email address would work)based on their selection (3 or less out of 10 choices).

Can someone please help me out? I have a okay knowledge of HTML, but I don't know JavaScript and hence I'm having a lot of trouble figuring it out. I have looked up various posts on the internet, but I couldn't find something that was pretty similar and worked.

Also, I am using WordPress, and since I need to add Javascript to the page, I installed a plugin called Exec-PHP Plugin. It seems like it works, however please do let me know your opinion.

Thanks so much, really appreciate any help!

EDIT: This is the code I tried. Its what I found when I looked through various posts. Its not exactly what I mentioned in this question, since like I mentioned before I do not have any previous knowledge of JavaScript. Here, its basically supposed to send a message to the email based on a single drop-down selection. I tried it, but it did not work (I changed the destination emails). 
Thanks!

```
 <form id="contactForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" minlength="2" placeholder="Your Name&hellip;" required>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email&hellip;" required>
        <input id="name2" type="text" name="name2" placeholder="Your Last Name&hellip;" required>
        <select id="department" type="text" name="department">
          <option value="customer" name="customer">I am a customer</option>
          <option value="distribution" name="distribution">department in distribution</option>
          <option value="press" name="press">I am with the press</option>
          <option value="career" name="career">department in a career position</option>
          <option value="other" name="other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message&hellip;" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send away!">
    </form>
    <?php

// We use the name2 field as bait for spambots.  It's display is off,
// so humans wouldn't know to enter anything into it.  Robots would, 
//  so we ignore submissions with info in name2.

$mail_sent = false;

if(sizeof($_POST) && $_POST["name2"] == "") // receiving a submission
{   
    define("SUBJECT",   "Visitor Message from Website");

    // production recipient:
    define("RECIPIENT", ".$department.");

    // prep our data from the form info
    $senderName     = $_POST['name'];
    $senderEmail    = $_POST['email'];
    $department     = $_POST['department'];
    $subject        = SUBJECT; 
    $messageBody    = $senderName . ' ('.$senderEmail.') wrote in '.$department.':

' . $_POST['message'];

    if($department == 'customer') { //if customer was selected
    $to = 'customer@gmail.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'distribution') { //if distribution was selected
    $to = 'distribution@email.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'press') { //if press was selected
    $to = 'press@email.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'career') { //if career was selected
    $to = 'career@email.com';
    }

    else if($department == 'other') { //if other was selected
    $to = 'other@email.com';
    }

    // From 
    $header         = "from: $senderName <$senderEmail>";

    // To
    $to = RECIPIENT;

    // Send it!
    $send_contact = mail($to, $subject, $messageBody, $header);

    // Check success of send attempt
    if($send_contact){
        // show thankyou screen
        $mail_sent = true;
    }
    else {
        // send failed.
        echo "ERROR";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a sample code to give you, but roughly, it would be something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function my_js_submit()
   {
       // check the email input fields that you care about.
       if(document.getElementById("email1").value != "" &&
          document.getElementById("email2").value != "" && 
          document.getElementById("email3").value != "")
       {
           document.forms["my_form"].submit(); //this will call the php where you do 
                                            //emailing
       }
       else
       {
          alert("Please fill in all three emails");
       }
   }
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- submit_handler.php is where you send emails -->
<form id="my_form: method="post" action="submit_handler.php">

<input type="text" id="email1"  />
<input type="text" id="email2"  />
<input type="text" id="email3"  />    
<input type="text" id="message" />
<button onclick="my_js_submit();"> Submit </button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP most basic code (name this file submit_handler.php):

```
<?php
    $to = $_POST['email1'] . "; " .  $_POST['email2'] . "; " .  $_POST['email3'];

    $subject = "Email subject"; 

    $message = $_POST['message']; 

    $from = "From: your_email@yourDomain.com"; 

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$from); // The Mail function at work

    // Redirect your user to a page of your choice 
    header("Location: http://www.some_page.com");
```

?>

Comment: Thanks for your help. Though I understand some of the code, I have no knowledge of JavaScript, so it would be great if you or someone else could help me out some more!

Comment: can you design the form? do check if an input in the form is filled, you could use: `if(document.getElementById("email1").value  != "")`

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. As a side note, this is a link where I got the code in my question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278569/send-email-to-multiple-recipients-based-on-selected-option-in-php
I dont know why it doesnt wok though

Comment: what part? you are running this on a server right? and you have the ability to execute PHP in this server?

Comment: Oh! I am under the assumption here that you are trying to learn how to code this using javascript and php because it is what you gave as an example that you were trying, but the quickest, easiest solution is to create a form and embed it in your website instead of doing all this work yourself. I have done this in the past, a free service that has never let me down is http://www.wufoo.com/ This website allows to create a form, set conditions, etc and then gives you the code to embed it in your website. Is this what you want?