# Based on selection, "mailto:" link changes to "mailto: variable" using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form. The way it would work is that the user chooses an option from the drop-down list. They then click the confirm location button. Finally they click the send email link. Basically when they click the confirm location button, it changes the mailto link in the send email link, based on their selection in the drop-down list.
However, what i cannot figure is how to change the mailto link to  mailto my variable t which holds the value of the email address (based on the selection.)
(See 3rd last line in code)
Please help!

```
<form>Select your place:
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="email@domain.com">Location 1</option>
        <option value="email2@domain.com">Location 2</option>
        <option value="email3@domain.com">Location 3</option>
        <option value="email4@domain.com">Location 4</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Confirm Location</button>
<a id="myEmailList" href="mailto:">Send email</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResult() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    t = x.value
    document.getElementById("myEmailList").href = "mailto:"t;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, concatenate the values?

```
document.getElementById("myEmailList").href = "mailto:"+t;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Its only my second day with JavaScript hence the difficulty. I request you to please have a look at my other question, its really troubling me at the moment. Thank you! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344199/send-email-based-on-selection-with-file-upload/25344323

Answer (score 0):

Select elements don't have a value on their own; you need to get the value of the selected option. Try this:

```
t = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
```

You also are missing a + when setting the href. Should be:

```
href = "mailto:" + t
```

Comment: The + worked. As for the first suggestion, it works either ways for me? :S